# Multiple PCIe Functions in Real User Applications (EP mode)

Tags: fpga, pcie

According to PCIe specification, a PCIe device may contain a collection of up to 8 functions. If a PCIe is configured to a specific endpoint, under what circumtances does it need multiple functions? Why single function is not sufficient, it is a implementation option or it is a must to have a multi functions EP in certain usage models?

Can any expert correlate this usage model to a real life PCIe user application?

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple functions allows a device connected by a single link to be able **to appear as multiple independent devices** to the host operating system. This allows seperate drivers to be written for each function which can make development easier such that you don't have to write one driver to support the multiple functionality, you can use general drivers to support each.

A simple real world example of this is some graphics cards appear as two or more devices - a graphics card, and a sound card, etc. This split allows the graphics and sound to both be used as legacy compatible devices without the need to be able to load special driver software to be able to split them.

Modern motherboards have chipset controllers (such as Intel PCH) that present multiple functions on a single PCIe link. This allows things such as network controllers, sound controllers, serial interfaces, etc. to appear as independent devices, even though they physically share the same bus. Imagine having to have software to deal with a network controller and a sound controller together. It's much easier to split them up.

[image]

Comment: The PCH is a bad example because those are all "root complex integrated enpoints," as you can tell from having a bus number of zero and a nonzero device number.  (The device number is always zero, except for root complex integrated endpoints and downstream switch ports)

Comment: @alex.forencich Perhaps, but they are specifically different functions, which wach show up as an independent device to the host system.

Comment: But my point is that they are not located in an endpoint, which is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @alex.forencich My point is that it doesn't really make any difference. They both use functions which is what the op is asking about. The graphics card is an example of an endpoint with two functions.

Comment: @alex.forencich & Tom, Can i summarize my understanding as below?

Basically, function is just like device. function come in place just because we want to have 2 different things happen in the same endpoint (device), to share the same PCIe link. Hence, 2 functions can be used to seperate 2 different operations, Due to this, RP is able to see 2 different cetegory operations happen in the same endpoint.

Comment: @alex.forencich & Tom, i also want to clarify the reason why i emphasize my question for endpoint. This is simply because i thought endpoint is meant for specific application (For example, i buy a specific device for sure is targeted on specific applications)

I did not think further that, a same endpoint is used to run so many different applications. But do we really need so much functions for EP? Even for NIC, is it really practical to used up to 256 functions?

Comment: The endpoint VS function distinction comes down to how routing works in PCIe. At the far end of a PCIe link, you have one bus number with a single endpoint with device number 0. This endpoint also contains at least function 0. You can't have an endpoint without at least one function, the spec does not allow it. And you can't have functions that aren't associated with an endpoint or the root complex.

Comment: And yes, NICs can use a lot of functions, at least in the context of highly virtualized systems - think cloud providers such as Amazon AWS, Google GCP, Microsoft Azure, etc. Take a look at a datacenter grade NIC such as the Mellanox connectx 5. Apparently that one supports up to 1000 functions, though I'm not sure how they implement that, maybe they're emulating a PCIe switch.

Comment: I checked the Mellanox connectx 5 page (https://network.nvidia.com/files/doc-2020/pb-connectx-5-en-card.pdf). It supports up to 512 virtual functions and 8 physical functions via SR-IOV.

Answer (score 2):

Each PCIe function generally appears as an independent device to the operating system.  As a result, supporting multiple functions can have many benefits.  So much so that PCIe also supports ARI, which effectively merges the device number into the function number, enabling a single endpoint to support up to 256 functions instead of the usual 8.  Coupled with SRIOV, this can be used to support very low overhead virtualization.

In the case of a computer with a single operating system running on it, multiple functions can be useful for attaching separate driver instances to different functions.  For example, a dual port NIC can expose two functions, and the OS treats each function as a separate single port NIC and loads one copy of the NIC driver for each function.  Another example is a video card, which could present one function for the graphics card itself and a different function for the integrated sound card that is used to embed audio in the HDMI data stream.  In this case, different drivers would be loaded for each of the two functions.

When multiple operating systems are present in a virtualized environment, PCIe passthrough can be used to directly present a PCIe device to a virtual machine, with no driver modifications or host OS/hypervisor involvement.  This works fine for some devices, but for things like NICs it is rather limiting - passing the whole device through to a VM means you need a whole NIC for each VM.  But this passthrough is done on the level of the PCIe functions, not whole devices, so if a NIC exports several functions, then it's possible to pass one function through to each VM.  This is the whole point of SRIOV (single-root IO virtualization) - slice and dice each device up into multiple functions, give each VM its own dedicated virtual device, and push the required arbitration, multiplexing, and demultiplexing out of the host OS/hypervisor and into the device hardware itself.

This has become quite common on NICs intended for datacenter applications - NICs can be split up into a number of virtual NICs, each with its own PCIe function and MAC address.  These virtual functions get passed into virtual machines via PCIe passthrough, and the NIC performs the arbitration and multiplexing for outgoing traffic and demultiplexing for incoming traffic in hardware.  The upshot is this increases efficiency by removing load from the CPU.  The downside is that since the multiplexing and demultiplexing is handled in hardware, it's limited by the capabilities of the NIC hardware.  This has resulted in the rise of smart NICs, which are highly configurable and can even contain a number of processing cores directly on the NIC to handle more complex packet processing tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple functions can be useful when the same device does multiple things. For instance my NVIDIA GPU is a single PCIe device with 4 functions. The output of `lspci` for that device on my PC looks like this:

```
$ lspci -s 1:00 -k
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C Port Policy Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 USB Type-C Port Policy Controller
```

All four of these functions are located within the same PCIe device (and chip!) but they get separated. In fact, you can see from the output above that all four functions have different kernel modules ("drivers") attached to them. In this case, having the function field just means that all four of these devices get to share the same PCIe infrastructure.

Another example I've seen where this is used is for multi-port network cards. This effectively allows the user to work with each port separately. In the specific case of network cards, this makes it really easy to pass one network card to a virtual machine in a server, for instance. The now ancient Intel 82571EB takes advantage of this, for instance.

What's really happening here is something like this:

```
-------                    ------------------
| CPU | <=(INTERNAL BUS)=> | PCIe ROOT PORT |
-------                    ------------------
                                   ^
                                 (PCIe)
                                   v
                           ------------------
                           |  PCIe EndPoint |
                           ------------------
                          ^             ^
                (On-silicon internal buses and magic)
                         v              v
                ----------------     ----------------
                | Network card |     | Network card |
                |       A      |     |      B       |
                ----------------     ----------------
```

The main processor (or root port, technically) is able to see each of the far-end "functions", while only one PCIe connection is needed.